# how to know which cell has been changed after fired 'onResizeEnd' event on DHTMLX grid?

Tags: grid, dhtmlx

I trying to get cell information after fired 'onResizeEnd' event on DHTMLX Grid.

as you know, DHTMLX grid provide dynamic change of cell width using mouse drag.

I really want to know.. how to get information about cell or cell index which cell width changed after mouse drag.

I want to make individual grid list setting.  so I need every columns width and those width changed to what.

my English is really poor.  but I think you guys understand what I want to know.

plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
// Attach event handler to listen to when column resize is finished.    
grid.attachEvent("onResize",function(cellIndex, colWidth){
    console.log("Now resizing col#" + cellIndex + " it is this wide: " + colWidth);
    return true;
});
```

If you want all column widths, you do this:

```
var sizes = [];
for (var c=0; c<grid.getColumnCount(); c++){
    sizes.push(grid.getColWidth(c));
}
```